# Fazer extensão PDO_SQL funcionar no PHP (sql server) socorro

Tags: php

Não consigo fazer a extensão do PDO_SQL entrar no PHP de forma alguma
estou com o Wampserver com PHP Version 7.1.9
no php.ini as extensões estão assim:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

Os arquivos estao no diretorio das extensoes do php corretamente
mas no phpinfo, nao entra de forma alguma o sqlsrv 
rodei este script abaixo para testar mas o retorna falso

```
<?php
var_dump(extension_loaded('pdo_sqlsrv'));
?>
```

Não sei mais o que fazer para estas extensão funcionar, ja tentei de tudo inclusive em outras maquinas
quem puder me dar um auxilio agradeço muito

Joab

Answer (score 0):

No `WampServer` você deve abrir o arquivo `C:\Wamp\bin\php\php<version>\phpForApache.ini`, procurar por `;extension=pdo_sqlsrv` e remover o ponto-e-vírgula, caso não tenha essa linha, basta adicionar e reiniciar o `WampServer`

Verifique também se a extensão é compatível com a versão do seu PHP

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php#ref.pdo-sqlsrv.installation

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/sql-connection-libraries#anchor-20-drivers-relational-access